# How to set text value for job-posting.experienceRequirements structured data?

Tags: structured-data

Google search console says there is an issue with the `experienceRequirements`attribute of this job posting :

https://emploi.sanitaire-social.com/offres-emploi/offre_auxiliaire-de-vie-579314

Actually I'm putting text in this property, and the doc says I can do so, but I can't figure it out :

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/job-posting?hl=en

```
experienceRequirements  
OccupationalExperienceRequirements or Text
```

How can I use simple text ?